# Remove instance name from site url

Tags: force.com-sites

I am setting up a public site in salesforce, is there any way to hide the instance name from the public site

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are creating site from developer edition Salesforce doesn't add instance name in site URL. The production Site URL look like

https://mycompany.secure.force.com and  https://mycompany.force.com

You can also link it with your custom domain

[Set up Custom Domains for Salesforce Sites and HTTPS support for Branded Custom Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205653&type=1)